# How to prove that $B$ is invertible and to find $\det A$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

I try to solve a question but can't find a way.

> Given $A,B$ are $4\times4$ matrices and
> $$
> A-A^2B-2I = 0 
> \quad\text{and}\quad 
> 3BA^2+A^2-3A = 0 
> $$
> I need to prove that $A,B$ are invertible and to find $\det A$.

I succeeded to find that $A$ is invertible using $A(I-AB) = 2I$.

But I can't find why $B$ is invertible no matter how I do algebraic manipulations.

Please help, even a hint will help, because I have no clue.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $3BA^2+A^2-3A=0$ implies $3BA+A-3I=0$, from which we get
$$
(3B+I)A=3I
$$
which, by using the fact that for an invertible matrix $M$ we have $MM^{-1}=M^{-1}M=I$, we achieve
$$
A(3B+I)=3AB+A=3I \implies AB=I-\frac{1}{3}A.
$$
Now, replace for $AB$ in $A-A^2B-2I=0$ and enjoy the rest of the journey for yourself!

Comment: thank you!, but I still can't figure it out, i dont find a way that tell me B is invertible.

Comment: Try to show that $B$ has no zero eigenvalues by using $B=A^{-1}-\frac{1}{3}$ and $A$'s eigenvalues from Cayley-Hamilton's theorem.

Comment: oh finally i think i got it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The first equation gives $$AB=I-2A^{-1}$$ Multiply the second equation by $A$ on the left side and by $A^{-2}$ on the right side to get $$AB=I-{1\over 3}A $$ Now you can solve for $A$ to get $A^2=6I,$ which implies that $\pm \sqrt{6}$ are the only possible eigenvalues of $A.
$ The equation $B={1\over 6}A-{1\over 2}I$ implies that $B$ is invertible, as $0$ cannot be its eigenvalue.

The condition $A^2=6I$  does not determine $\det A, $ but $(\det A)^2.$